# Adding falcon application routes on a root directory

Tags: python, falconframework

I am writing a falcon application for serving some webpages. Now I have some js, css files under /js, /css under the root dir. These /js and /css directories can have multiple subdirectories and the files may be located inside one of the sub directories.

I want to have a falcon apps route added such that the webpage requests for

```
/js/subdir1/subdir2/temp.js
/js/subdir1/temp2.js
```

can be satisfied by the same responder method.

But when I tried, having a route added like

```
app.add_route("/js/{filename}", ResourceClass())
```

the request for /js/subdir1/subdir2/temp.js does not reach the responder.

The responder I have is as below,

```
class ResourceClass(object):
    def on_get(self, request, response, filename):
        file_path = os.path.join(path_to_js,filename)
        serve_file(response, file_path)
```

serve_file will create the appropriate response and return it.

I want the filename to be populated as

```
"subdir1/subdir2/temp.js" for "/js/subdir1/subdir2/temp.js" and
"subdir1/temp2.js" for "/js/subdir1/temp2.js "
```

How can I add the route and add the responder ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache you can configure your site as below:

```
Alias /js/ /path/to/wsgi/js/

<Directory /path/to/wsgi/js>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/wsgi/script.py

<Directory /path/to/wsgi>
    <Files script.py>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

restart apache and under `http://localhost/js` URL you should reach your static files

Answer (score 0):

Falcon 1.4.1 (or older) offers static file serving with prefix for entire directory.

```
asset_path = "/var/www/html/js/"
js_path = asset_path + "js/"
api.add_static_route('/assets', asset_path)
api.add_static_route('/assets/js', js_path)
```

..will serve any `/var/www/html/js/*.js`.